PySpark cumulative sum of contiguous rows over partition
I have a table that holds reports that come in for different entities, and the state the entity is in at the time of the report. It is important to know the total duration of each occurrence of an entity existing in state 2.  The reports are not regular so I cant just add one year for each report, but for the sake of simplicity, I have gone for whole years between each report here.
The table looks like this:



entity_id
state
report_date




A
1
2000-01-01


A
2
2001-01-01


A
2
2004-01-01


A
1
2005-01-01


A
3
2007-01-01


A
2
2008-01-01


A
3
2009-01-01


B
2
2000-01-01


B
2
2001-01-01


B
3
2002-01-01



I calculate the decimal period between each reporting date (accurate to the nearest month, which is good enough for what I need) with the following:
import pyspark.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

window = Window.partitionBy('entity_id').orderBy('report_date')
df = (
    df.withColumn(
       'report_interval', 
       F.datediff(
           'month', 
           F.lag(F.col('report_date')).over(window), 
           col('report_date')
       ) / 12.
    )
    .fillna(0, subset='report_interval') 
)

This gives the intermediate table:



entity_id
state
report_date
report_interval




A
1
2000-01-01
0.0


A
2
2001-01-01
1.0


A
2
2004-01-01
3.0


A
1
2005-01-01
1.0


A
3
2007-01-01
2.0


A
2
2008-01-01
1.0


A
3
2009-01-01
1.0


B
2
2000-01-01
0.0


B
2
2001-01-01
1.0


B
3
2002-01-01
1.0



What I want to end up with is a dataframe of the form:



entity_id
state
report_date
report_interval
state_2_cumulative_duration




A
1
2000-01-01
0.0
0.0


A
2
2001-01-01
1.0
0.0


A
2
2004-01-01
3.0
3.0


A
1
2005-01-01
1.0
4.0


A
3
2007-01-01
2.0
0.0


A
2
2008-01-01
1.0
0.0


A
3
2009-01-01
1.0
1.0


B
2
2000-01-01
0.0
0.0


B
2
2001-01-01
1.0
1.0


B
3
2002-01-01
1.0
2.0



I tried the following code but of course, at the time the task is scheduled, that state of the cumulative duration column is zero, so I don't actually get a cumulative sum.
df = df.withColumn('state_2_cumulative_duration', F.lit(0))
df = (
    df.withColumn(
        'state_2_cumulative_duration', 
        F.when(
            (lag(col('state')).over(window)  == 2),
            col('interval') + lag(col('state_2_cumulative_duration')).over(window)
        ).otherwise(0)
    )
)




entity_id
state
report_date
report_interval
state_2_cumulative_duration




A
1
2000-01-01
0.0
0.0


A
2
2001-01-01
1.0
0.0


A
2
2004-01-01
3.0
3.0


A
1
2005-01-01
1.0
1.0 <- wrong result


A
3
2007-01-01
2.0
0.0


A
2
2008-01-01
1.0
0.0


A
3
2009-01-01
1.0
1.0


B
2
2000-01-01
0.0
0.0


B
2
2001-01-01
1.0
1.0


B
3
2002-01-01
1.0
1.0  <- wrong result



I could achieve what I want with the code I have if I iterate it infinitely, but that is obviously not feasable. I don't understand rowsBetween well enough to know if it would help here.
Explicit desired output:



entity_id
state
report_date
report_interval
state_2_cumulative_duration




A
1
2000-01-01
0.0
0.0


A
2
2001-01-01
1.0
0.0


A
2
2004-01-01
3.0
3.0


A
1
2005-01-01
1.0
4.0


A
3
2007-01-01
2.0
0.0


A
2
2008-01-01
1.0
0.0


A
3
2009-01-01
1.0
1.0


B
2
2000-01-01
0.0
0.0


B
2
2001-01-01
1.0
1.0


B
3
2002-01-01
1.0
2.0




Can you describe the line "A 3 2007-01-01 2.0 0.0" why it is getting 0?

Sure. The state of the entity not 2 in the previous row. Therefore it triggers the otherwise clause and receives 0 as an output. I only care about the duration of time an entity is in state 2 for. All other states I dont care about.

You did help me spot an error in the code I provided here where I had it checking the current row, rather than the previous row, but that was a copy error and didnt affect the output I presented.

ok, you are only considering state = 2? all other states are irrelavant right? And you need the time an entity is in state 2 for a specific time, right? Can you add the expected output as DataFrame please?

All other states are irrelevant for the duration calculation, yes. But if an entity enters state 2 for a period of time, then another state, and then goes back into state 2, that is to separate instances of state two and I need durations for both.
The expected output is the second from last table. I will copy it back to the bottom. Unless you mean a different output format?

Honestly it is hard to understand you. I still dont know where "A 1 2005-01-01 1.0 4.0" the 4.0 and "B 3 2002-01-01 1.0 2.0" the 2.0 comes from and how you gonna calculate it.

That is the problem. I dont know how to calculate it either.
For "A 1 2005-01-01 1.0 4.0", the entity A has just entered state 1 after a period of time being in state 2. We received 3 reports between 2001 and 2005, the initial one that changed the state of the entity to state 2 in 2001, then 3 years later a second report stating that the entity was still in state 2, and then a report in 2005 stating that the entity had moved back to state 1. So the duration that it was in state 2 was the three years between 2001 and 2004, and the 1 year between 2004 and 2005 for a total of 4 years.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
